# Cannot find HttpApi construct in CDK v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add an HttpApi to my project that already uses CDK v2.
I'm able to retrieve the HttpApi class from `@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigatewayv2.HttpApi.html

But I'm not able to retrieve the construct in the new v2 `aws-cdk-lib` module:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigatewayv2-readme.html

Has the package been moved in v2?

Also, what is the difference between HttpApi and this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sam.CfnHttpApi.html?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CDK v2's L2 `HttpApi` construct is in `@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha`.  In CDK V2, experimental modules are published [in separate "alpha" packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html).

`CfnHttpApi` is the [L1 construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html) that represents the [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html) `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api` resource.  Under the hood, `HttpApi` has a `CfnHttpApi` as a child node.  `Cfn`-prefixed constructs are published in `aws-cdk-lib` because they are stable.

Here's where to find the constructs:

| Package | CDK Version | Constructs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [aws-cdk-lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigatewayv2-readme.html) | v2 | `CfnHttpApi` (L1, stable) |
| [@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha-readme.html) | v2 | `HttpApi` (L2, experimental) |
| [@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-readme.html) | v1 | `HttpApi` (L2, experimental), `CfnHttpApi` (L1, stable) |

Comment: `import * as apigw from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha'` solved my issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

### New location of HttpApi construct

From [migrating to AWS CDK V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html):

> Experimental constructs are provided in separate,
> independently-versioned packages with names that end in alpha and an
> alpha version number that corresponds to the first release of
> aws-cdk-lib with which they are compatible.

Since the HttpApi construct is considered experimental, it has been moved to a separate package:

[Link to construct page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigatewayv2-alpha.HttpApi.html)

[Link to overview of new experimental package labelled alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha-readme.html)

### Difference between CfnHttpApi, CfnApi and HttpApi

[CfnHttpApi documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sam.CfnHttpApi.html) (Not experimental)

[CfnApi documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigatewayv2.CfnApi.html) (Not experimental)

[HttpApi documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigatewayv2-alpha.HttpApi.html) (Experimental)

CfnHttpApi and CfnApi are L1 constructs, which means they directly convert to a single CloudFormation resource block. HttpApi is a L2 construct, which are usually more complex and can convert to one or more CloudFormation resource blocks. [This CDK Developer guide page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_l1_using) on Constructs provides more details on how L1 and L2 constructs work.

CfnHttpApi and CfnApi are both CloudFormation resource types which create HTTP APIs, but CfnHttpApi is the [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) version of CfnApi. Quoting [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification.html), AWS SAM templates are an extension of AWS CloudFormation templates, with some additional components that make them easier to work with.

Comment: It's almost 2 years later, it seems we can assume the L2 constructs will remain in experimental state indefinitely?

Comment: @cib you mean almost 1 year later? Track module graduation here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/discussions/24038

Answer (score 0):

please do update your aws-cdk-lib version to `"aws-cdk-lib": "^2.114.0"`,